# How to use arangodb collection in multi-process

Tags: arangodb

I use Anyevent::Fork::Pool or Parallel::ForkManager to create 100 perl process. I'd like to create database and collection in Global, and use collection object in function. But it doesn't work.
My sample code is following:

```
use ArangoDB;
my $itdb = ArangoDB->new(
{
    host       => '10.211.55.18',
    port       => 8529,
    keep_alive => 1,
    timeout    => 10,
}
);
my $Node_Coll = $itdb->( 'Node' );

...

sub function{
    $Node_Coll->count();
}
```

It's feedback "Error Can't call method "http_get" on an undefined value". I print $Node_Coll in global and function. It's different.

In global, the $Node_Coll is normal. But it's wrong in function. 
In function:
    bless( {
                 'db' => undef,
                 'name' => 'Node',
                 'status' => 3,
                 'code' => 200,
                 '_api_path' => '/_api/collection/250177068120',
                 'id' => '250177068120',
                 'connection' => undef
               }, 'ArangoDB::Collection' );

If I put "my $Node_Coll = $itdb->( 'Node' );" in local function, It's OK. Just like this.
    sub function{
        my $Node_Coll = $itdb->( 'Node' );
        $Node_Coll->count();
    }

I don't know why it works like this. I think it maybe use one socket in multi-process when "$itdb->( 'Node' );" in global.
Because "$itdb->( 'Node' );" will send a http_get request, it'll produce extra load, especially in multi process enviroment. It's better if we can save it.

UPDATE BY 8/10/2014:
Data preparation:
    Insert some data into Collection 'Node'.
Execute method:
 1. keep the script.  And execute $./count_srv.pl
 2. modified the script. Comment "my $Node_Coll = $itdb->( 'Node' );" in count(). Uncomment in global. And execute $./count_srv.pl

count.pm is following:

```
package Count;
use ArangoDB;

my $itdb = ArangoDB->new(
{
    host       => '10.211.55.18',
    port       => 8529,
    keep_alive => 1,
    timeout    => 10,
}
);
#my $Node_Coll = $itdb->( 'Node' );

sub count{
    my $Node_Coll = $itdb->( 'Node' );
    my $count = $Node_Coll->count();
    print "The count is ", $count, "\n";
}
```

count_srv.pl is following:

```
use Parallel::ForkManager;
use count;

my $process_num = 10;
$pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new($process_num);

for(1..$process_num){
# Forks and returns the pid for the child:
my $pid = $pm->start and next;

Count::count();

$pm->finish; # Terminates the child process
}
$pm->wait_all_children;
```

Comment: Could you post the example client program here (either the one with Pool or with ForkManager) with both the working and the non-working variants? Otherwise it's hard to tell. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your response! I have attached my example program. The difference is "my $Node_Coll = $itdb->( 'Node' );" in global or in count().

Comment: It seems to me that using the same connection in multiple parallel threads does not work, as the client threads will send their data over the same connection in parallel, interleaving their writes and reads. The outcome will be non-deterministic and probably garbled. I think it would be much better to create one connection per forked thread, which is guaranteed to be used by one thread only. I think this is sensible and the overhead of establishing a few connections should be negligible as each worker is probably issuing a lot of follow-up requests anyway.

Comment: My product program is based on event. If it received a event, Count::count() will be executed once. So I don't like to put "$itdb->( 'Node' );" into count(), it's a extra workload for executing it per event. So I think it's difficult to "implement create one connection per forked thread" and "establishing a few connections should be negligible" at the same time.

Comment: Understood. But multiple threads writing data into the same shared connection will probably not work either. For example, if one thread writes to the connection and waits for the response, you cannot be sure that another of your threads will "steal" the response from the connection first. So I think you will need multiple connections. Maybe it is okay to create a pool of threads with one connection each, and wake one up when an event occurs?

Comment: Thanks! I tried to use Anyevent::Fork::Pool to do it. It's OK. It provides "init       => "insert::init"," option. I put "ArangoDB->new" and "$itdb->( 'Node' )" into init(), init() only execute once, and count() will be executed many times. It's seem to be perfect now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for this to work with multiple processes, you will also need multiple connections (ideally one per process). 
Otherwise the single (shared) connection will be used in parallel by multiple processes, and this might mess it up.

It should be ok to create a pool of connections beforehand and pass an idle connection from the pool to a child process when it forks. When the child process terminates, you can return connections to the pool. I have no idea how this works with Perl, just wanted to share the general idea.